# Problema no retorno do código (equação de segundo grau)

Tags: c

O retorno do código abaixo está "-nan", e não estou identificando o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct variaveis
{
    float a,b,c;
};

float delta (float a, float b, float c){
    float a1=a,b1=b,c1=c;
    a1 = pow(b1,2) - 4*a1*c1;
    return a1;
}

float x1 (float a,float b,float c){
    float a1 = a, b1=b, c1=c;

    printf("x1 = %f\n", (b*-1 + sqrt(delta(a,c,b)))/2*a);

}

float x2(float a, float b, float c){
    float a1=a,b1=b,c1=c;
    printf("x2 = %f\n", (b1*-1 - sqrt(delta(a1,b1,c1)))/2*a1);

}

int main(){
    float a, b, c;

    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    x1(a,b,c);
    x2(a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu programa só calcula raízes reais. Verifique se delta é negativo e, neste caso, calcular as raízes imaginárias de sua equação (a+b*i) ou informe que não tem raízes no campo dos reais.

Comment: É sempre melhor usar `double` (\*) quando se pretende valores de virgula flutuante. (\*) *lembra-te de corrigir scanfs*

Answer (score 3):

Muitas coisas estranhas, mas o `nan` se deu porque você fez `delta(a,c,b)`, invertendo os valores de `b` e `c`. Isso possivelmente está implicando em um retorno negativo de `delta` e, assim, tentar calcular a raiz quadrada de um valor negativo, entrando no domínio dos números complexos, não suportado pela função.

Outros detalhes são:

1) Declarar uma `struct` e não utilizá-la:

```
struct variaveis
{
    float a,b,c;
};
```

2) Definir retorno `float` de funções sem retorno:

```
float x1 (float a,float b,float c){
    float a1 = a, b1=b, c1=c;

    printf("x1 = %f\n", (b*-1 + sqrt(delta(a,c,b)))/2*a);

}

float x2(float a, float b, float c){
    float a1=a,b1=b,c1=c;
    printf("x2 = %f\n", (b1*-1 - sqrt(delta(a1,b1,c1)))/2*a1);
}
```

3) Redeclarar as variáveis de forma desnecessária em muitos lugares:

```
float a1 = a, b1=b, c1=c;
```

4) Não utilizar parenteses para garantir a precedência dos operadores:

```
(b*-1 + sqrt(delta(a,c,b)))/2*a
```

Aqui o valor será dividido apenas por 2 e multiplicado por `a`, não dividido por `2*a` como deveria ser. Precisa ser `/(2*a)`.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente correção. A struct se deve ao fato que estou estudando threads na faculdade, e li que parâmetros em thread são passados através de estruturas. Ela ainda não foi usado mas pretendo, pois preciso fazer uma equação de segundo grau através de threads. Há muito tempo não mexo com C.

Answer (score 0):

Ao trabalhar com ponto flutuante em C, deve-se checar as exceções do ambiente de ponto flutuante (Floating Point Environment) habilitando o #pragma FENV_ACCESS

Em termos do seu problema, bastava ter identificado que a função delta pode gerar números negativos. A função sqrt() dispara a exceção FE_INVALID (C99) quando números negativos são passados como argumento para a função. Assim sendo, bastava adicionar a seguinte checagem após o cálculo das raizes:

```
if(fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)) 
      puts("FE_INVALID was raised");
```

Isso e mais informações podem ser encontradas no link correspondente: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions

Comment: Muito obrigado :)